# What to do with US retirement plan after moving to Canada

Tags: united-states, canada, international, retirement-plan

I have accumulated a few tens of thousands of USD in 403(b) retirement plans with TIAA and Fidelity. I recently moved to Canada. I am not planning to return to the US anytime soon or ever. Is it wise to keep these plans in the US, given that I will not be contributing to them anymore? Or should I consolidate them into a supplementary retirement plan in Canada?

Comment: What kind of accounts? 401k? IRA? Something else? How much of the balance is after-tax money? There are tax and penalty considerations that may vary by account type and contribution type.

Comment: They are 403(b)